# Lenovo Caps Lock,Num Lock Key Pop-Up turn off on display

Tags: window

Search for services in the window search bar and drop down Lenovo and function key services.
And disable that service. This will hide the pop-up window, but you can still use the fn key. It is different from simply deleting HOTKEY from the startup program.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a30vm.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLChO.png)
This is not a question. I'm just writing to let you know what I've solved.

Comment: Lenovo Legion 5 Pro here. You just made my day! Thanks a million.  I disabled and stopped the service.